Why does SoX changes bitrate when trimming an audio file? (MacOS)
When I am trimming an mp3 audio file with SoX in terminal on MacOS, bitrate of the audio changes to 128 kbps. If the original file's bitrate is lower than 128 kbps, then it increases to 128 kbps. If it's higher than 128, then it decreases to 128.
Here's the commands I used:
sox Love\ For\ Sale.mp3 Love\ For\ Sale2.mp3 trim 0 -5
and
sox The\ Nearness\ Of\ You.mp3 The\ Nearness\ Of\ You2.mp3 trim 0 -10. The terminal didn't output anything.
And here's a screenshot
I was expecting for bitrate to stay the same. Is it possible?

I don't think there's a way to automatically keep the same bitrate within sox. You can specify a desired bitrate with -C though, such as
sox orig.mp3 -C 320 new.mp3 trim 0 -10

which will set the bitrate to 320kbps.
If you really need to do it automatically, you can get a little creative:
soxi -B ./orig.mp3 | rev | cut -c2- | rev | xargs -I {} sox ./orig.mp3 -C {} ./new.mp3

soxi -B <filename> - returns the bitrate of the file (ex. 128k)
rev | cut -c2- | rev - removes the letter k from the end
xargs -I {} sox ./orig.mp3 -C {} ./new.mp3 - pipes the result into the conversion command
